# Communication between Windows services on Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows-service, windows-server-2019, named-pipes

I have some custom made Windows services, that communicate over Named Pipes on local network with other application on another server. This setup worked perfectly on WS 2008 R2 and WS 2016 servers, but i cant get it work on WS 2019 for some reason. All the servers are set up absolutely in the same way.

I have tried to to elevate all the permissions to Administrator, but it did not help.

Do you know about any change made in WS2019, that could cause these problems?

Edit:
I have tried to install SMBv1 on the servers, but it didnt help.

Edit 2:
I dont think problem is in the named pipes. I am using ServiceController to connect to the service. Even when i try to "sc query" the service i get "[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 5:" error.
i think there must be some kind of change in service controlling in WS2019, but i dont know what to look for.

Comment: I'm guessing this is an SMBv1 problem, which is not installed in Windows Server 2019 by default. What does a network capture on the the "client" and "server" show?

Comment: What specifically goes wrong?  Do you get an error code or message at any point?

Comment: I get "Cannot open <service_name> service on computer <computer_name>" error on client side.

Comment: The first thing I suggest you try is to create a file share on the server and see whether or not the user can access it from the client, i.e., is this a problem with SMB in general or just with that particular named pipe?

Comment: The second thing I suggest you try is running Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) on the client while attempting to connect.  I think that should show you the actual error code that the client is receiving.  If not, if this is in-house code perhaps you can ask the developer to write a version that reports the error code rather than just a generic message?

Comment: Finally, can you check whether there is a delay (30 seconds or so) before the client reports the error?  If so, you should triple-check the firewall settings on the server, also whether there might be any other firewall device between the client and server.

Comment: I've just tried running `sc query` remotely against a Windows 2019 server and it worked.  Are you absolutely certain that the account you are using has administrative privilege on the server?  Have you tried connecting to the server's C$ share, for example?